# SVG object following path

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path

I have a svg-path:

```
 <path id="path" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 0.00,250.00
       C 0.00,250.00 33.75,335.50 125.00,375.00
         216.75,415.00 250.00,500.00 250.00,500.00
         250.00,500.00 285.00,408.25 377.25,377.75
         469.50,346.75 500.00,250.00 500.00,250.00
         500.00,250.00 0.00,250.00 0.00,250.00 Z
       M 90.00,308.50" />
```

I want another (svg) object to follow the path. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [AnimateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/animateMotion)

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
<path id="pathID" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 0.00,250.00
       C 0.00,250.00 33.75,335.50 125.00,375.00
         216.75,415.00 250.00,500.00 250.00,500.00
         250.00,500.00 285.00,408.25 377.25,377.75
         469.50,346.75 500.00,250.00 500.00,250.00
         500.00,250.00 0.00,250.00 0.00,250.00 Z
       M 90.00,308.50" />   
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="15" fill="red" > 
        <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" >
            <mpath xlink:href="#pathID" /> 
        </animateMotion>
     </circle>  
    
</svg>
```

### Three-button operation:

- forward movement of the red ball
  moving forward means moving from the starting point of the path (the starting point of drawing the path in the vector editor)
- backward movement of the red ball
- mid-way red ball

```js
var circ =  document.getElementById("circle2");   
var animation1 = document.getElementById("forward");
function forwardSVG(){
      
  circ.style.opacity = "1";
  animation1.beginElement();
 
} 
var animation2 = document.getElementById("middle")
function middleSVG(){
     circ.style.opacity = "1";
  animation2.beginElement();
}  

var animation3 = document.getElementById("back")
function backSVG(){
     circ.style.opacity = "1";
  animation3.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<div id="pathContainer4">
  <button id="btn1" onclick="forwardSVG()">forward</button >
  <button id="btn2" onclick="middleSVG()">Middle<b/utton >
  <button id="btn3" onclick="backSVG()">Back</button >
</div> 
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 600 600" > 
 <path transform="translate(0 -200)" id="pathID" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 0.00,250.00
       C 0.00,250.00 33.75,335.50 125.00,375.00
         216.75,415.00 250.00,500.00 250.00,500.00
         250.00,500.00 285.00,408.25 377.25,377.75
         469.50,346.75 500.00,250.00 500.00,250.00
         500.00,250.00 0.00,250.00 0.00,250.00 Z
       M 90.00,308.50" />   
    <circle id="circle2" cx="0" cy="-200" r="15" fill="red" opacity="0"  >  
    
  <animateMotion
    id="forward"
    dur="2s"
    begin="indefinite"
    repeatCount="1"
    keyPoints="0;1"
    keyTimes="0;1"
       calcMode="linear"  >
   <mpath href="#pathID" />
  </animateMotion> 
  <animateMotion
     id="middle"
     dur="2s"
     begin="indefinite"
     repeatCount="1"
     keyPoints="0.5;1"
     keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear" >
   <mpath href="#pathID" />
     </animateMotion> 
     <animateMotion
     id="back"
     dur="2s"
     begin="indefinite"
     repeatCount="1"
     keyPoints="1;0"
     keyTimes="0;1"
     calcMode="linear" >
   <mpath href="#pathID" />
     </animateMotion>
         </circle>
</svg>
```